# Which field to use to filter documents by ID in Firestore dashboard?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-console

I am using the firestore dashboard to browse through some documents in my collection. In one particular case, I am looking to find a document in a collection called private, but when I enter "id" in the "Filter by field" and specify the ID that I want it to match, the dashboard doesn't find anything.

All I want to do is a find a specific document in a collection via the ID using the dashboard. Any idea how to do this? Seems such a mundane feature that I am just surprised firebase wouldn't have it?!

[image]

Comment: Unless you have actually created an 'id' field in each document, you cannot do this. You can only query by the fields within the document, and not by the documents UIDs. The workaround would be when you create a document, add it's id as a field to the document after you've created it

Comment: Ah, I see! That makes sense, sadly.

Answer (score 5):

you can search for one specific document by clicking on the "table header", in your case, "Home > private > 0EU..."

[image: firebase screenshot]

Comment: This is valid answer.

Answer (score 3):

The value you type there is taken as the name of a field to search for.  "id" means the name of the field called literally "id".  There is one special field name "__name__" which is taken by the Firestore SDK to mean the document ID in some cases (normally specified as `FieldPath.documentId()`), but apparently the console does not accept that.

What you have here is, in my opinion, a valid feature request for the Firebase console, and you can file that with [Firebase support](https://support.google.com/firebase/contact/support).

Comment: Thanks! Just sent a feature request, wonder if they will get back.

Comment: Has this feature been added? I have the same issue, and cannot filter a collection by a reference ID.